# Internal functions in PowerShell Module

Tags: powershell, module

I'm writing a module, and I have some helper functions that I don't want exposed, but I do want available to module functions internally. I have set up my directory structure like:

```
root\
..Private
....Invoke-PrivateTest.ps1
....private.psd1
....private.psm1
..Public
....Get-Something.ps1
....Public.psd1
....Public.psm1
..test.psd1
```

I've setup a repository on github https://github.com/jpbruckler/test that has all the module files in it.

The behavior that I'm expecting is that Get-Something is a public function. When running `Get-Command -Module Test` it should be listed. On the contrary, `Invoke-PrivateTest` should not be in the output of that command.

When calling `Get-Something` it should output the text `Invoke-PrivateTest called`. Instead, I get an error stating that the command Invoke-PrivateTest doesn't exist.

I am explicitly saying in `test.psd1` that only the `Get-Something` function is to be exported.

Both the Private module and the public module are being called via the `NestedModules` property in `test.psd1`. Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Nested modules a independent from each other. If you want to use `Private` from `Public`, then `Public` should import `Private`.

Comment: That I didn't know. I must not be looking in the right place for module documentation. This gives me some ideas on how to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@PetSerAl pointed me in the right direction. Ultimately this came down to a scoping issue. The way I had the module arranged, each sub-module would need to make a call to load the private module, which is a bunch of code duplication - and also what I was hoping to avoid by splitting out some helper functions.

To get it all to work, instead of multiple sub modules, I just broke up the `Public` folder into sub folders that will hold scripts that do similar things, basically removing all the .psd1 and .psm1 files from the `Public` directory. I did the same thing for the `Private` directory. This left me with a bunch of loose .ps1 files that I load in `test.psm1` with the following code:

```
$Private = (Get-ChildItem -Path (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot 'Private') -Filter *.ps1)
$Public = (Get-ChildItem -Path (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot 'Public') -Filter *.ps1 -Recurse)


foreach ($Script in $Public) {
    . $Script.FullName
    Export-ModuleMember $Script.BaseName
}

foreach ($Script in $Private) {
    . $Script.FullName
}
```

I've modified the test module at https://github.com/jpbruckler/test to reflect the changes I made.

Comment: I think this solution could be quite useful. The linked GitHub repo is not available.  Could you either make the code available on GitHub or edit this answer to include more of the source code?  Working examples are gold. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have other reasons to put the code into separate (sub)modules I'd keep it in one folder and control what's exported via the function names. Use "official" notation (`<Verb>-<Noun>`) for the names of public functions and omit the hyphen in the names of private function (`<Verb><Noun>`). That way you can export public functions in your global .psd1 like this:

```
FunctionsToExport = '*-*'
```

Comment: The primary reason I don't use this approach is because non-standard names is not best practice, and can lead to a bunch of ugly warning text being output to the console.